# How to remove all backslashes in a string in tcl

Tags: tcl

```
*/*CKGT*0P*\ */*CKGT*ON*\\ */*CKGT*0T*\\
```

How could I remove the backslashes in the above string ? the length of the string will differ

Answer (score 0):

The `string map` command is designed for this sort of task:

```
set inputString {*/*CKGT*0P*\ */*CKGT*ON*\\ */*CKGT*0T*\\}
# */ # This line is just to stop the StackOverflow syntax highlighter from being silly

set removed [string map {\\ ""} $inputString]
puts $removed
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple code snippet to verify:

```
set a {*/*CKGT*0P*\ */*CKGT*ON*\\ */*CKGT*0T*\\}
puts $a
regsub -all {\\} $a {} b
puts $b
```

output:

```
tclsh test2
*/*CKGT*0P*\ */*CKGT*ON*\\ */*CKGT*0T*\\
*/*CKGT*0P* */*CKGT*ON* */*CKGT*0T*
```

BING!

Thanks,
Mr. Bordoloi